# Querying other shema syscolumns table

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I am executing SQL query to check weather schema **abc_hist** has table **@table_name** or not. but following query fails to return any result even when table exist i.e., which make if condition false every time:

```
use abc
go
----procedure---
IF EXISTS(select  1
                  from    abc_hist..syscolumns
                  where   status & 128 = 128
                          and     object_name(id) = @table_name )
----procedure---
```

So, Question is there any other way to effective check table existence in other schema or correction in my current sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
select 
  CASE WHEN status & 8> 0 THEN 'allows null' ELSE 'no nulls' end, 
  CASE WHEN status & 16 > 0 THEN 'check constraint exists' ELSE 'no checks' end, 
  CASE WHEN status & 128 > 0 THEN 'is identity' ELSE 'not identity' end,
  *
              from    abc_hist..syscolumns
              where   object_name(id) = @table_name
```

It will say "not identity" in every row, which means the `@table_name` you passed in as a parameter has no identity columns, and because you made it a condition of your where clause that the results must be an identity column in order to be returned, there are no results, so EXISTS is always false

Remove the WHERE clause on status if you want to use this query to check on a table's existence:

```
IF EXISTS(select  1
              from    abc_hist..syscolumns
              where   object_name(id) = @table_name )
```

Comment: Thanks. your use of status made it more understandable.